# Why do I get an error when running NetSim via CLI Mode?

Tags: networking, simulation

I get the following error when running NetSim v7.1 (from www.tetcos.com) via its command line interface. The input given is -

```
C:\Program Files\NetSim Standard\bin>NetSimCore.exe -apppath  
C:\Program Files\NetSim Standard\bin -iopath  
C:\Users\Sachin Kumar\AppData\Local\Temp\NetSim -license 5053@192.168.0.185
```

I/O warning:

```
failed to Load external entity C:\Users\Sachin "file:///C:\Users\Sachin/Configuration.xml"
```

I checked and the configuration file is present in the temp path (%temp%\NetSim)

*Can someone please help?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the I/O path has white space, you should have it within double quotes. The correct way would be

```
C:\Program Files\NetSim Standard\bin>NetSimCore.exe -apppath ^
    C:\Program Files\NetSim Standard\bin -iopath ^
    "C:\Users\Sachin Kumar\AppData\Local\Temp\NetSim" -license 5053@192.168.0.185
```